# Open .xproj in Visual studio 2015 CTP 6

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

I have followed the [instruction](https://github.com/aspnet/home#getting-started) to install latest KVM ( now called DNVM) and cloned some of the ASP.net projects to my local.
But after last week's changes, such as [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EntityFramework.Core/EntityFramework.Core.xproj), visual studio fails to open the xproj and gives error like "error  : Value cannot be null.Parameter name: projectMoniker". 
Does anyone know what I missed?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTP6 was built for beta3 of the ASP.NET 5 stack. You should not expect it to handle anything newer than that, especially considering all the tooling has been given new names since beta3 was built. You need to wait for a new CTP build if you wish to continue using Visual Studio with the **latest** beta4 stuff. If you want to use CTP6 make sure you use beta3 packages for everything, including the kvm from the master branch. As pointed out in the comments, there is a compiled list of the beta4 packages that still work with CTP6 [over on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/377).

If you wish to work with the latest dev bits I advice you to use your favorite editor plus [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/) to get some auto-complete goodness. Then use the commandline tooling to build and run your application.

Comment: Actually you may work with beta4 with CTP 6. But they renamed everything again, [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/377) shows us the latest beta 4 version we can work with in CTP 6. In addition a guy offers a way to make CTP 6 recognize the new dnx folder but use it at your own risk.

Comment: Yep. Great. I edited my answer to clarify. :) thanks

Comment: @Ricky: you can switch to `master` branch (which has the released version) and VS CTP6 should be able to open it fine.

Comment: Marked as answer. Thank you for all the great contribution.