# ASP.Net 5 Beta 8 xproj cannot be opened

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, beta

I just installed the new release of ASP.Net 5 beta 8. I ran DotNetVersionManager-x64.msi and then WebToolsExtensionsVS14.msi. I tried to open a simple app that worked in beta 7 and it won't load the project with a message

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
> Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL
> Microsoft .NET Framework
> Version 4.6.00079

I then tried to create a new ASP.Net 5 web project and got this:

> The project file 'c:\users\myfolder\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication3\src\WebApplication3\WebApplication3.xproj' cannot be opened.
>
> The project type is not supported by this installation.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the DotNetVersionManager and WebToolsExtensionsVS14 with the same result.

Comment: A similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075247/open-xproj-in-visual-studio-2015-ctp-6

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it by doing this

Close VS, then delete the folder at %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache and restart – Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

Thank you @SayedIbrahimHashimi

Comment: I accidentally loaded VS2015 while the tools were in the middle of installing. This fixed it though - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started building applications with ASP.NET 5 is to install the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 (including the free Community edition).

1. **Install [Visual Studio 2015](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=532606)**

   Be sure to specify that you want to include the Microsoft Web Developer Tools.
   [image: ../_images/web-dev-tools.png]
2. **Install [ASP.NET 5](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=627627).**

   This will install the latest ASP.NET 5 runtime and tooling.
3. **Enable the ASP.NET 5 command-line tools. Open a command-prompt and run:**

   `dnvm upgrade`

   This will make the default .NET Execution Environment (DNX) active on the path.
4. **On Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 you will also need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4.**

You are all set up and ready to write your first ASP.NET 5 application!
[Reference...](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html#install-asp-net-5-with-visual-studio)